# The sign convention paradox

Tags: optics, conventions, reflection

I encountered a type of problem in optics where we have to shift an object in front of mirror or lens but there has been an element of confusion in it. When we shift something like 'd' distance away or closer to the mirror to some existing distance like 40 cm, and we use the mirror formula should we ideally include the factor of sign convention and write (-40-d)   or should we write (-40+d) because sometimes we have something shifted but we don't we if it is shifted ahead or behind, please explain how to properly define sign convention for shifting cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like distance is measured from the mirror to the object.  The new distance is $(40+d)$, with d being a positive quantity moving the object away from the mirror (increasing the distance) and negative for moving closer to the mirror.  Whatever the sign convention is, it's applied to all of the new distance, $(40+d)$.  So if the formula used to read $-40$, it now reads $-(40+d)= -40-d$.